# How can I display two query result in a single gridview?

Tags: c#, gridview

I am trying to display two query result in a single gridview. I surfed a lot in internet but I did not get a proper answer. Kindly help anyone. My sample query

```
    int shift=0;
    int month = Convert.ToInt32( ddmonth.SelectedItem.Value);// should be in the format of Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, etc...
    int yearofMonth = Convert.ToInt32(ddyear.Text);
    DateTime dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(month + "-" + "01-" + yearofMonth);
    string month1 = dateTime.Month.ToString();
    int year = Convert.ToInt32(ddyear.Text);
    DataRow dr;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Sunday");
    dt.Columns.Add("Monday");
    dt.Columns.Add("Tuesday");
    dt.Columns.Add("Wednesday");
    dt.Columns.Add("Thursday");
    dt.Columns.Add("Friday");
    dt.Columns.Add("Saturday");
    dr = dt.NewRow();


    for (int i = 0; i < DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month); i += 1)
    {
        qry = "select s.Shiftname from ShiftType s,ShiftAllocation a where s.ShiftID=a.ShiftID";
        empdt = conn.gettable(qry);
        string data = empdt.Rows[shift][0].ToString();
        empdt.Columns.Add(data);
        row = empdt.NewRow();
        if (Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime.AddDays(i)).ToString("dddd") == "Sunday")
        {
            dr["Sunday"] = i + 1;
            row[data] = empdt.Rows[shift][0].ToString();
        }
        if (Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime.AddDays(i)).ToString("dddd") == "Monday")
        {
            dr["Monday"] = i + 1;
            row[data] = empdt.Rows[shift][0].ToString();
        }
        if (dateTime.AddDays(i).ToString("dddd") == "Tuesday")
        {
            dr["Tuesday"] = i + 1;
            row[data] = empdt.Rows[shift][0].ToString();
        }
        if (dateTime.AddDays(i).ToString("dddd") == "Wednesday")
        {
            dr["Wednesday"] = i + 1;
            row[data] = empdt.Rows[shift][0].ToString();

        }
        if (dateTime.AddDays(i).ToString("dddd") == "Thursday")
        {
            dr["Thursday"] = i + 1;
            row[data] = empdt.Rows[shift][0].ToString();
        }
        if (dateTime.AddDays(i).ToString("dddd") == "Friday")
        {
            dr["Friday"] = i + 1;
            row[data] = empdt.Rows[shift][0].ToString();
        }
        if (dateTime.AddDays(i).ToString("dddd") == "Saturday")
        {
            dr["Saturday"] = i + 1;
            row[data] = empdt.Rows[shift][0].ToString();
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            empdt.Rows.Add((row.ItemArray));
            row = empdt.NewRow();
            continue;
        }
        if (i == DateTime.DaysInMonth(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month) - 1)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            empdt.Rows.Add((row.ItemArray));
            row = empdt.NewRow();
        }

    }
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

This is my actual code  I am trying to create an event Calender. My expected o/p is just like
     [image]

Now GridView displays only dt values and I want to display the query result  empdt as the events

Comment: why dont you write a query to combine both data and bind

Comment: use union...for this

Comment: @SANDEEP, see my updated question. What to do in this type of cases?

Comment: Your sample data doesn't help understanding the problem. Can you give us more accurate data to work with? Ie: column names of both queries and 3 or 4 rows of data.

Comment: @Serv, My question is simple I just want to display th dt value and dr2 value in a  gridview1

Comment: we dont know how dr2 looks like. We also don't know if they have the same columns or not and why a join is not possible. I wouldn't be asking if you would have provided the basic information needed to understand what you are asking.

Comment: @ Serv, Kindly find my original code

Answer (score 1):

```
string qry="select Name,Age from table Sample1 inner join table Sample2 on table Sample1.CustomerID = table Sample2.CustomerID";

dr1=con.query(qry);
GridView1 DataSource=dr1;
GridView1 DataBind();
```

Both table must have same column name "CustomerID". Then you can use this query.

Answer (score 0):

Join Both tables using Join keyword and then bind the data to GridView.

Comment: see my udated question. What to do in this type of cases?