# How to perform dayrender event in Button Click event?

Tags: c#, calendar

I am developing an event caleneder using dayrender event. I have a dropdown to select month and another one dropdown to select year. And I need to get the calender as per my query result. Now when I run the program calender showing data as per today's date. How can I set it to display data only with selected month and year??
My code is

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
  e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Aqua;
  DateTime date = e.Day.Date;
  string day = date.Day.ToString();
  string abc = date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");     
  SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString);
  string command = "select s.Shiftname from ShiftType s,ShiftAllocation a where s.ShiftID=a.ShiftID and  a.Date= '" + abc + "' and Month='" + ddmonth.SelectedItem.Value + "' and Year='" + ddyear.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
  SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(command, conn);
  SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
  DataSet ds3 = new DataSet();
  sda1.Fill(ds3);
  var rows1 = ds3.Tables[0].Rows;
  foreach (DataRow row1 in rows1)
  {
    string shift = Convert.ToString(row1["Shiftname"]);
    e.Cell.Text = e.Cell.Text + day;
    e.Cell.Text = e.Cell.Text + shift;
  }
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

I need the dayrender function works only after I select the month and year(Only after button click). Anybody Please help me

Comment: You know that this event is called for **every day** in the calendar? Don't select from the database there. That's very inefficient. You could hold a collection which was pre-loaded, then you just need to look into that collection(f.e. a `Dictionary<DateTime, string>`) in `DayRender`.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter, I need my selected month and year datas output. Is there any other way to perform it??

Comment: @Tim Schmelter, I need an another help after this please find the below link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29205509/how-can-i-display-two-query-result-in-a-single-gridview